# Find which input (radiobutton) is checked in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, radio-button

I have in my aspx:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  CellPadding="10">
       <ItemTemplate>
             <input type="radio" name="Flights" id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdFlight") %> "/>
           <p >From: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromLoc") %>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromCountry") %>
             </p>
           <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FromAirport") %> Leaves at: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Time") %>
            <p >To: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToLoc") %>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToCountry") %> 
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ToAirport") %> </p>
        </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:DataList>
```

As you can see there is a radiobutton of type Input (html control), to which I give the ID of the Flight from my bound data.
Now in my code-behind I need to find that input control that is checked. How do I achieve this?
I tried:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
```

etc.. but then how to know if it is Input-Radio and if it is checked

Comment: Is there a reason, why you don´t use the `asp:RadioButton` element instead of `input` ?

Comment: Hallo, yes because the parser did not like it, I have asked also about this, and it was given as answer to use the input.
if i use: id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdFlight") %>
on a asp:radiobutton the parser throws an exception

Comment: do you know the exact id of the element in your code behind, if you loop trough the items?

Comment: My purpose is to know the Id of the flight the user will choose. Every Flight has an Id in my datatable, then I databind with the datalist. But I need to detect the user action that chooses the ID. The problem is I cannot bind the Id to the radiobutton.and later detect it, because Asp does not let me link this Id to any information attached to the asp controls.

Answer (score 0):

First off all add the `runat="server"` attribute to your input control, so that you can access the control on the server:

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="Flights" id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdFlight") %> "/>
```

Then you can loop trough all controls, within an item like this:

```
private string GetSelectedFlightID()
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in dl1.Items)
    {
        foreach (var control in item.Controls)
        {
            if (control is HtmlInputRadioButton radioButton)
            {
                if (radioButton.Checked)
                    return radioButton.ID;
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not find the control unfortunately

Comment: Try to add `runat="server"` to the input control. Otherwise your backend won´t know the control.